# Footable does not sort by data-type = "number" using CodeIgniter and JSON

Tags: json, sorting, codeigniter-3, footable

I am new using Footable and I cant sort by data-type="number" (Everything else works correctly).

My Footable Code is:
`

```
<table
id="tabla"
class="table table-striped table-bordered"
data-paging="true"
data-paging-count-format="{CP} de {TP}"
data-sorting="true"
data-filtering="true"
data-filter-connectors="true"
data-filter-delay="-1"
data-filter-min="0"
data-filter-placeholder="Buscar"
data-empty="Sin resultados"
data-show-toggle="false"
data-toogle="true"
>
<thead id="thead"><tr>
<td data-name="fila" data-title="#" data-type="number" data-sorted="true"></td>
<td data-name="id" data-title="ID" data-type="number"></td>
<td data-name="numero" data-type="number" data-title="Nro."></td>
<td data-name="descripcion" data-title="Descripcion" breakpoints="xs sm"></td>
<td data-name="ciudad" data-title="Ciudad" data-formatter="vinchuca"></td>
<td data-title="Acciones" data-formatter="acciones"></td>
</tr></thead>
</table>

<script>
    $.get(baseurl+"ABM/readTodo",function(data){
        futable = FooTable.init('#tabla',{
        "rows":JSON.parse(data)
        });
    })
</script>
```

`

[Graphic example of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dftnv.png)

the codeIgniter JSON output is:

```
   "rows":[{"fila":"1","id":"1","numero":"1","descripcion":"pruebas","idCiudad":"2","ciudad":"LORETO"},{"fila":"2","id":"2","numero":"2","descripcion":"esta es la segundas","idCiudad":"2","ciudad":"LORETO"},{"fila":"3","id":"3","numero":"4","descripcion":"ESTA ES OTRA TABLA","idCiudad":"2","ciudad":"LORETO"},{"fila":"4","id":"4","numero":"20","descripcion":"ESTA ES LA ULTIMA","idCiudad":"1","ciudad":"SANTIAGO DEL ESTERO"}]
    });
```

if I remove the "" like this:
"fila":1,"id":1,"numero":1,"descripcion":"pruebas","idCiudad":"2","ciudad":"LORETO"}

Footable works, what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was:

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

I changed with:

```
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

and now is working perfect!